# standard structure for angular via npm

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am looking for standard structure for starting my angular 1.5 project, I am interested to get it from npm with very basic func,to add bootstraup and so on.
something like: [betterjs](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure)

I looked at google but didnt find any solution, hope you can advise.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a really good guild with ready code [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)